# Enabling support for AddressSanitizer in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, gcc

The question essentially is how to compile a program that uses AddressSanitizer in FreeBSD.

I use FreeBSD 10.0 (64-bit). I am trying to compile the following code with `-fsanitize=address` flag:

```c
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile with `clang` as `clang -fsanitize=address file.c`, I get the following error message:

```
/tmp/t-tEh7oh.o: In function `main`:
file.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `__asan_report_store4`
/tmp/t-tEh7oh.o: In function `asan.module_ctor`:
file.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `__asan_init_v3`
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I compile with `gcc48` as `gcc48 -fsanitize=address file.c`, I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lasan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In my GNU/Linux system I have `libasan.*` files somewhere in a file system. But I am unable to find ones in FreeBSD - neither in `/usr/ports`, nor via `pkg`.

How should I better make that working?

**Upd.** Responding to a comment, I added output of `gcc48 -v` (more precisely, output of `gcc48 -fsanitize=address file.c -v`):

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc48
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0
Configured with: ./../gcc-4.8.3/configure --disable-bootstrap --disable-nls --enable-gnu-indirect-function --libdir=/usr/local/lib/gcc48 --libexecdir=/usr/local/libexec/gcc48 --program-suffix=48 --with-as=/usr/local/bin/as --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/local/lib/gcc48/include/c++/ --with-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld --with-pkgversion='FreeBSD Ports Collection' --with-system-zlib --with-ecj-jar=/usr/local/share/java/ecj-4.5.jar --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,java --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/man --infodir=/usr/local/info/gcc48 --build=x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 (FreeBSD Ports Collection) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fsanitize=address' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/local/libexec/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/cc1 -quiet -v file.c -quiet -dumpbase file.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase t -version -fsanitize=address -o /tmp//ccjvAeJG.s
GNU C (FreeBSD Ports Collection) version 4.8.3 (x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final 183502), GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=98 --param ggc-min-heapsize=128184
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/../../../../../x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (FreeBSD Ports Collection) version 4.8.3 (x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final 183502), GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=98 --param ggc-min-heapsize=128184
Compiler executable checksum: 6bc4873e12afab16db5dd7bf12b3232f
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fsanitize=address' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/local/bin/as -v -o /tmp//ccBydWt7.o /tmp//ccjvAeJG.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/local/libexec/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/:/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/../../../../../x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/:/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/../../../../../x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/lib/:/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fsanitize=address' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/local/libexec/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -V -dynamic-linker /libexec/ld-elf.so.1 /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/crti.o /usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/crtbegin.o -L/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/../../../../../x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/lib -L/usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/../../.. /tmp//ccBydWt7.o -lasan -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.0/4.8.3/crtend.o /usr/lib/crtn.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.24
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64_fbsd
   elf_i386_fbsd
   elf_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_l1om
   elf_l1om_fbsd
   elf_k1om
   elf_k1om_fbsd/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lasan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What is the output of `gcc -v`?

Comment: @eyoung100, please find that in the updated version of the question.

Comment: Don't hate the messenger, but I needed to make sure you were running 4.8.  I'm not experienced with building a custom port, but here is what you need to do: Download the [Patch File Here](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/downloads/list), then manually rebuild the Port to include the custom patch.  On gentoo, we do this by using a local portage tree.  Surely there is a BSD equivalent.

Comment: @eyoung100 Indeed there is. Place the patch in the port's `./files` subdirectory, and ensure its name begins with `patch-`. The ports system will apply the patch before it goes on to configure and build the port.

Comment: @D_Bye When you manually add a patch, it might be deleted when you update the ports tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `llvm37` from ports. It builds the sanitizers by default on AMD64.